# Nuxt/Vue development server runs on <hostname> instead of localhost

Tags: localhost, nuxt.js, vue-cli, hostname, web-development-server

I've created a new project with `create-nuxt-app` and after the initial configuration and installation, running `yarn dev` starts the development server on `<hostname>:3000` instead of the expected `localhost:3000` as reported also in the official docs.
In my case, my hostname is `opensuse-kde` so the server is started on `opensuse-kde:3000`;

A similar thing happens also when starting a project with `vue-cli`, which runs on `<hostname>:<port>` instead of `localhost:<port>`.

What can be the cause of this behavior? Is there a way to have these development servers use `localhost` as they are supposed to do?

If it matters, I'm using openSUSE Linux.

Comment: Does setting the host in `nuxt.config.js` manually (either to `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`) work? https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/

Comment: @Phillip yes, by setting it manually it works, but it is not exactly what I was looking for. I'd like to have the default behavior by, well, default :)